# How to use multiple SqlDataReader in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I use `SqlDataReader` connection1 inside that I use another `SqlDataReader` connection2. So connection open issue occurring connection1 open. How to resolve it? Kindly provide a solution

Comment: Please share your code. Also, both connection1 and connection2 pointing to same database?

Comment: If it's a `SqlDataReader`, giving it a name of `connection1` is **very bad** and violates the "Principle of Least Surprise": If I see a variable called `connection1`, I would assume right away that this is a `SqlConnection`  but most certainly **NOT** a `SqlDataReader` ........ you should name those `reader1`  and `reader2` or something like that!!

Answer (score 0):

1. First create different connection, datareader... object
2. and close the connection datareader if data not read

**example code**

```
string connectionString1 = "Data Source=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;";
string connectionString2 = "Data Source=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;";
//Create the command 
string sqlSelect1 = "SELECT TOP 5 CustomerID, AccountNumber FROM Sales.Customer";
string sqlSelect2 = "SELECT TOP 5 CustomerID, AccountNumber FROM Sales.Customer";
//open the connection
SqlConnection objConn1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString1);
SqlConnection objConn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString2);
// Create the command and open the connection
SqlCommand objcommand1 = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect1, objConn1);
SqlCommand objcommand2 = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect2, objConn2);
objConn1.Open();
objConn2.Open();
// Create the DataReader to retrieve data
SqlDataReader DR1 = objcommand1.ExecuteReader())
SqlDataReader DR2 = objcommand2.ExecuteReader())
while (DR1.Read())
{
if(DR2.Read())
{
    //YOUR CODE
}
else
{
DR2.Close();
}
}
DR1.Close();
DR2.Close();
objConn1.Close();
objConn2.Close();
```